# Find entries in same table WITHOUT similar location

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Imagine I have a table of fast food restaurants (`FASTFOOD`). Each of them has geo coordinates set in columns `GEO_X` and `GEO_Y`, as well as a column `FRANCHISE`. Franchise may be MCDONALDS or BURGERKING.

I want to select all Burger Kings which do NOT have a McDonalds within a specific distance, measured in geo coordinate degrees.

How do I do this?

I AM able to list the Burger Kings that DO have a McDonalds within a certain distance:

```
select t.* 
from FASTFOOD t
  INNER JOIN FASTFOOD s ON (ABS(t.geo_x - s.geo_x) < 0.01 AND ABS(t.geo_y - s.geo_y) < 0.01) 
WHERE t.FRANCHISE= 'BURGERKING'
  AND s.FRANCHISE = 'MCDONALDS';
```

But I have no idea how to find the "opposite".

The result sets of my query are the same whether I use an `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, or `FULL OUTER JOIN`, as all entries do have set geo coordinates.

Comment: What is the definition of "geo" coordinate?  Is this latitude/longitude, points on a flat 2D grid, something else?

Comment: I believe I am misunderstanding the data you have in your tables but could you change the - for both the t.geo_x - s.geo_x and t.geo_y - s.geo_y to a +? Again I believe I am misunderstanding the data within the tables but to me that would get the opposite of the function shown

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

--below mentioned 'geo_z' is specified distance between two FRANCHISE'S

```
select * 
from (
  select t.* 
  from FASTFOOD t 
    inner join FASTFOOD s on t.PrimaryKey=s.PrimaryKey 
    where ABS(t.geo_x-t.geo_y) > geo_z
) d 
where d.FRANCHISE='BURGERKING'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I AM able to list the Burger Kings that DO have a McDonalds within a certain distance

use 
[all burgerkings] except [burgerkings that have a mcd nearby] 
that should only leave those without one nearby